# Grep search +specific lines

Tags: linux, logging

I have to parse a very large file and I want to use the command grep (or any other tool).

I want to search each log file for the word "XYZ", then print 5 line above and then print 2 line occurring
anywhere before the next grep result.

for example:

```
sad  
as  
asd  
sd  
as  
XYZ  
LINE 1  
LINE 2  

SDSADA  
S  
ADA  
DADA  
DDA  
xyz  
LINE 1  
LINE 2
```

I am using

```
grep b-5"xyz" filename.txt|
```

i am not able to figure out after this

Comment: Use `-A 2 -B 5` options.

Comment: AFAIU OP wants `-B 5` for the first and `-B 2` for the second/following match.

Comment: -A 2 for next two line but I need LINE 1 and LINE 2 which may occur anywhere before the next grep seqrch

Answer (score 2):

The options are `-A` for lines after, and `-B` for lines before.

```
grep -A 5 -B 2 "xyz" filename.txt
```